# Manipulating CSV file via JSP page

Tags: jsp, csv

I could really use some help on this one.  I am being handed a CSV file that I need to modify and spit back out a new CSV file that will then be saved on the users local hard drive.  The changes I need to make are pretty simple.  Just add a break before each eMail address.  I am pretty new with JSP (not quite a year) so any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Why JSP?  That's not an appropriate choice of technology for this task.

Comment: You should do this in servlet.

Comment: You can add ordinary java code to a jsp file. But as skaffman wrote, use an appropiate technology for it. In example normal java class.
@Harry a jsp file is at last nothing else as a servlet

Answer (score 1):

... that operation would be best done in a Servlet instead.

[...read the file ..](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42)

[... parse it ...](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=1779B1F48861ED8B241CD028ED27ECA4?Id=87)

... sample:

```
try {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infilename"));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    process(str);
}
in.close();
```

} catch (IOException e) {
}

taken from [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ReadLinesFromFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

this can be complex in jsp but try this if possible.

1) take a responcemsg as string builder and append in that manner.
  String str = convertStreamToString(msg);

```
StringBuilder sb;
if(str!=null){
String[] rows = str.split("\n");
for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
String[] cols = rows[i].split(",");
sb = new StringBuilder();
if(cols.length>=2)
name=cols[0];                       
name = name.substring(1,name.length()-1);                           
value = cols[1];                            
dif = cols[4];
System.out.println(dif);
sb.append("<b>"+name+"</b>").append(":").append(value).append(":");
    }                       
out.print(sb.toString());   
System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
out.flush();            
}
```

2) take that string in jsp and split the string in your manner and again appent that in CSV file